# Binding a listbox/datagrid view manually with Data Table Vs binding it with Data Sets.Data Table[0] in c# winForms

Tags: c#, winforms

There are two ways in c# that I can bind my listbox with a datasource:
1) Query the SQL Server 2008 db and the query will return a Data Table which can use it to bind it to list box.
2) Create a new Data Set by right-clicking in the solution explorer and going through the wizard to complete it and finally calling the dataset.fill method to fill the data table which I can bind it to my list box.

I have a list box which displays the names of forms that I have created in C#. Basically this is used to grant which user has right on which form.

My question is which method should I go for? Currently I'm using method 1. Same question also goes for a data grid view.

Comment: Makes no difference at all.

Comment: With method 2 my code size will reduce. Right? But my solution-explorer size will increase with lots of datasets for each lisboxes and datagrid views. Isn't that?

Comment: In this matter yes it makes the difference. Personally I would suggest you the first option, meaning populating the DataTable via code.

Comment: Also please can you suggest me a case where I need to use DataSets? I only know when I build reports using built-in ms reports its necessary to create a dataset before binding it to report columns.

Comment: Well I have one simple tip, I would recommend using them when working with DataBases, it is not always good for optimization as sometimes its better to use other methods but IMHO they always make the code more clear and in general using datasets makes working with databases simplier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will go with datasets :-)

Answer (score 0):

It dosn't make any difference.

`DataSet.Tables[integer]` is a `DataTable`